# How to check for null elements in a list in a dataframe in np.where()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

My dataframe, df:

```
Col_A Col_B
Apple [1,2,3]
Banana [1,null,4]
Orange [6,null,null]
```

The nulls are represented as `np.nan`s in the dataframe. How can I check if all the values in each row of Col_B are null?
This is my `np.where`:

```
np.where(pd.isnull(df[Col_B]).all(), "Fail", "Pass")
```

However, I get a truth value is ambiguous even though I have a ".all()" there. Any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need to use `np.where()` here. You can try it two other ways:

```
df['one_bad'] = df['Col_B'].apply(lambda x: np.nan in x)
```

will return `True` if there's at least one np.nan in the list.
But you can use `np.isnan().all()` to check if all values are `np.nan`.

```
df['all_bad'] = df['Col_B'].apply(lambda x: np.isnan(x).all())
```

will return `True` if all the values in the list are `np.nan` and `False` otherwise.